# TSQL Accumulate rows every monday with distinct rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get a query that returns customers I've attended per day, and i have this dataset:

```
fecha      RecargadorPDV
2016/12/19     1
2016/12/19     2
2016/12/19     3
2016/12/20     1
2016/12/20     4
2016/12/20     5
2016/12/21     2
2016/12/21     6
2016/12/21     7
2016/12/21     8
..
...
2016/12/26     1
2016/12/26     2
2016/12/26     1
2016/12/27     2
2016/12/27     6
2016/12/27     7
2016/12/27     8

but the output I'd want to have is this:


             date          attended    acum_customers
            2016/12/19     3            3  -- Every monday it restart
            2016/12/20     3            5  
            2016/12/21     4            8  
            .
            ..
            2016/12/26     3        3 -- Every monday it restart
            2016/12/27     4        3 
            .
            ..
```

As you can see, every monday it restart the values and if some customers are in a date and in the next day are present it needs to be ignored.

Comment: some sample data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: I have placed up above (look here but the output I'd want to have is this:)

Comment: The expected output is ample, but is irrelevant without the sample data. You need to provide a small dataset and show the expected output on that dataset so we can clearly understand and accurately help. i.e. provide some test data that we can work with to obtain results that you provide.

Comment: Scsimon, I have updated my question. Hope this could be clear

Comment: thanks Luis. Is recargador a unique ID for a customer?

Comment: Thanks for the test data and clarification. Hopefully what i provided will work, or get you real close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second week `acum_customers` is off based off the test data so check on that. I also assumed that the `recargadorPDV`could only attend once per day since it's unique so I removed the one record noted below. With that... this should get you what you want. Let me know if it needs more explanation.

```
--change the @@DATEFIRST from 7 (english default) to 1 for the start of the week calculations
SET DATEFIRST  1;

--load some test data
declare @table table (fetcha datetime, recargadorPDV int)
insert into @table(fetcha, recargadorPDV) 
values
('2016/12/19',1),
('2016/12/19',2),
('2016/12/19',3),
('2016/12/20',1),
('2016/12/20',4),
('2016/12/20',5),
('2016/12/21',2),
('2016/12/21',6),
('2016/12/21',7),
('2016/12/21',8),
                    --this is the break in the weeks
('2016/12/26',1),
('2016/12/26',2),
--('2016/12/26',1), -- removed this value since a unique ID shouldn't be allowed to attend twice for a single day
('2016/12/27',2),
('2016/12/27',6),
('2016/12/27',7),
('2016/12/27',8)


--temp table to hold some aggregated data
if object_id('tempdb..#tempT') is not null drop table #tempT

select 
    y.YR
    ,y.WK
    ,y.fetcha
    ,count(y.recargadorPDV) as attend
    ,sum(y.CTforWK) as accum
into #tempT
from(
    select x.* 
    from
        (select
            fetcha
            ,recargadorPDV
            ,datepart(yy,fetcha) as YR
            ,datepart(wk,fetcha) as WK
            --the case statment is my way of assigning 1 to each recargadorPDV ONLY once for each week so the running total is correct, ignoring duplicates as you stated
            ,case when count(recargadorPDV) over (partition by datepart(yy,fetcha), datepart(wk,fetcha), recargadorPDV order by fetcha) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as CTforWK
        from @table) x) y
group by
    y.YR
    ,y.WK
    ,y.fetcha


--see the inital results without the running total
select * from #tempT

--see the final results with the running total
select
    a.fetcha
    ,a.attend
    ,sum(x.accum) as acum_customers
from #tempT a
inner join #tempT x on x.fetcha <= a.fetcha and x.YR = a.YR and x.WK = a.WK
group by a.fetcha, a.attend
order by a.fetcha

--change back the @@DATEFIRST setting
SET DATEFIRST  7;
```

Comment: Interesting. Our two answers differ in one basic question - do we want the data by calendar week by year, or for each seven day period?  If we cross years not on a Monday, we will have different answers for the crossover period.

Comment: Yeah I was t sure how he wanted to handle that so I'll give you +1 from my side @LaughingVergil

Comment: Yes it needs to be every seven day period (always restarting on monday). Which one would be the right answer?, I'm gonna test the sample by Scsimon right away.

Comment: @LuisCabezudo both of ours will work. How we handle the new year is just slightly different.

Comment: For now my database is backing up and i can't check the second answer, but the first one it doesnt return the output expected because on the 2016/12/26 the values needs to be restored (because of monday)

Comment: Did you set the DATEFIRST as I did at the top of the script? SET DATEFIRST  1; then at the end SET DATEFIRST  7; This is important for the datepart(wk,fetcha) calculation

Comment: By default i had DATEFIRST =1. But I think I'm gonna have a problem, how do i make this to make it work on a view, seems DATEFIRST sentence cant be used on a view

Comment: You never mentioned that in the original question so i didn't take that into consideration. You also can't use #tempTables in a view. Perhaps the @LaughingVergil answer is better for you then. I upvoted it myself.

Comment: Yes It's true, I have not mentioned it because i thought it was possible. THe answer from LaughingVergil doesnt work correctly as yours. I have tested yours and works wow really good and it's what i have expected.

Comment: well i can change it to a CTE but the datefirst would still have to be there. I'm sure I could make it work without it though. Why not just create a stored procedure?

Comment: Ok let me explain @SCSIMON, because when i place it on a SP  and then execute it on a Datamart named TABLEAU it returns error, for that reason I dont need it on a SP, furthermore I don't want my user have to execute a SP. Could you help to make it on a view. Your solution works really good.

Comment: Tableau and Spotfire both can handle procedures... just a FYSA @LuisCabezudo and it's invisible to the user.

Comment: I have placed on a SP and it works perfectly on Tableau. SCSIMON your solution was the best one here. Best Regards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132535/discussion-between-luis-cabezudo-and-scsimon).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that returns what you need for any arbitrary date. I have included sample data for a full week + two days to confirm its functionality.

```
DECLARE @t table (fecha date,
    RecargadorPDV int
    )
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2016/12/19', 1),
('2016/12/19', 2),
('2016/12/19', 3),
('2016/12/20', 1),
('2016/12/20', 4),
('2016/12/20', 5),
('2016/12/21', 2),
('2016/12/21', 6),
('2016/12/21', 7),
('2016/12/21', 8),
('20161222', 12),
('20161222', 1),
('20161222', 8),
('20161223', 11),
('20161223', 13),
('20161223', 15),
('20161223', 9),
('20161224', 1),
('20161225', 22),
('2016/12/26', 1),
('2016/12/26', 2),
('2016/12/26', 1),
('2016/12/27', 2),
('2016/12/27', 6),
('2016/12/27', 7),
('2016/12/27', 8)
;

With a as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        fecha,
        Dateadd(day, -(
            case 
                when datepart(weekday, fecha) >=2
                    THEN datepart(weekday, fecha) - 2
                ELSE 6
        END), fecha) as LastMonday
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT 
    a.fecha as [date],
--  count(Distinct(CASE when t.fecha = a.fecha Then t.recargadorPDV else -1 END)) - 1 as attended,
    SUM(CASE when t.fecha = a.fecha Then 1 else 0 END) as attended,
    Count(distinct recargadorPDV) as acum_customers
FROM @t t
INNER JOIN a
    ON t.fecha BETWEEN a.LastMonday and a.fecha

Group by a.fecha
ORDER BY a.fecha
```

Output of the above **(as corrected)** is:

```
date        attended  acum_customers
2016-12-19  3         3
2016-12-20  3         5
2016-12-21  4         8
2016-12-22  3         9
2016-12-23  4         13
2016-12-24  1         13
2016-12-25  1         14
2016-12-26  3         2
2016-12-27  4         5
```

Comment: If you will want to include days with no customers, you will have to incorporate a dates table of some sort into the report.

Comment: A tally table would be ideal for all dates without customers

Comment: This answer is not correct because on date 2016-12-26 the value attended must be  3 and acum_ustomers=3 (every monday needs to be restarted)

Comment: Yeah, I obviously suffered brain cramping while coding the Attended value. Editing above code with a fix - I will comment out the bad code and add in the correct code.